# RequireJS properly handling 404 on external dependency

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm unsure of how to handle a 404 on an external dependency from RequireJS. I've included a sample of my require.js file below:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: '/js/jquery-2.1.0.min',
    script1: 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/script1.min',
    script2: 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/script2.min',
  },
  shim: {
    script1: {
      deps:['jquery'],
      exports: 'script1'
    },
    script2: {
      deps:['script1'],
      exports: 'script2'
    }
  }
});

requirejs([
  'script1',
  'script2'
]);
```

I want to be able to handle the external dependency going down or being unavailable, without having a `Script Error`. Is the `Script Error` the correct behavior in that scenario? I imagine there must be a way to not include the scripts in the event of a 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

require can take an additional parameter for an error callback, like the following:

```
require(['script1', 'script2'], function (a, b) {
    // Normal execution
}, function (err) {
    // Error, such as a 404.
});
```

You could decouple loading each dependency separately if you wanted to, so you can perform custom error handling if script1 or script2 404s.

```
require([], function () {
    require(['script1'], function (a) {
        // Do stuff with a
    }, function (err) { });
    require(['script2'], function (b) {
        // Do stuff with b
    }, function (err) { });
});
```